# Operations on sub-lists in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 3]]
```

How to get the following effect in two steps ?:

1. `b = [[1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4, 3]]`
2. `b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 3]]`, it means:

   1.1. If the same values occur in the sub-list `b[i]` next to each other, then 
      one of these values must be deleted.

   2.2. If the same values appear in a given sub-list `b[i]` but not next to each 
      other, then the entire sub-list `b[i]` must be deleted.

Comment: What you tried yourself?

Comment: You've been asking a lot of questions, so I'm a bit worried. Maybe take a step back and revaluate your solution. I'm getting some [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) vibes here... make sure this is the only/best way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Maybe I'm too often changing the concept., but I'm a bit pissed off this project heh :) But I think this way will be good because I was not able to get all the combinations between the sub-lists.

Comment: I can see how an elegant, short solution would need some trickery, possibly using iterators/itertools. But a straight forward solution with loops is, well, straight forward. You should be able to at least begin to try implementing those. That will teach you some Python and you'll learn how to approach similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timegb is right. An elegant solution involves some amount of trickery and deception. I'll try and break down the steps.

- find all 2-combinations of your input using `itertools.combinations`
- flatten returned combinations with `map` and `chain`
- for each combination, group by consecutive elements
- keep only those that satisfy your condition by doing a length check.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, groupby

out = []
for r in map(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)), combinations(a, 2)):
     j = [i for i, _ in groupby(r)]
     if len(j) <= len(set(r)):
         out.append(j)
```

```
print(out)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 3]]
```

---

If you need only the first part, just find combinations and flatten:

```
out = list(map(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)), combinations(a, 2)))

print(out)
[[1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: I tried it from the `itertools()` or `product()`, but it missed that. thanks again! you probably never sleep :)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski, hah! Sleep? What is that? ;)

Comment: a little coffee and forward :))

Comment: I have one more question. Why does an `len(j) < len(r)` return an empty list? I think it should return list `out = [[1, 2, 3]]`.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski if you have consecutive duplicates, then you definitely have duplicates. So j cannot ever be smaller than set(r).

Comment: But not from 'set' only from the whole r :) But I already know where the problem was.